# Animate Background Color JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, background-color

After searching the internet, it seems like there are a variety of approaches to animating color via jquery.

What is the best way for me to animate the background color of my "wrapper" from #FFF to #000?

```
 var open = true;
    $(".btn-slide").click(function(){ 
        if(open){
        $("#wrapper").animate({
            width: 900,  
            }, 
            1000, function() {
        });
    open= false;
    }else{
        $("#wrapper").animate({
            width: 250,  
            }, 
            1000, function() {
    open = true; }
});
```

Thanks for your suggestions. I am very grateful for the input.

Comment: You could use jQuery UI's "animate color": http://jqueryui.com/demos/animate/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this

```
var open = true; 
        $(".btn-slide").click(function(){ 
        if(open){ 
        $("#wrapper").animate({ 
        width: 900, 
        backgroundColor: '#000' 
        }, 
        1000, function() { 
        }); 
        open= false; 
        }else{ 
        $("#wrapper").animate({ 
        width: 250,
        backgroundColor: '#000' 
        }, 
        1000, function() { 
        open = true; } 
        });
```

Comment: and you can use `toggle()` instead of `open` variable manipulation

Comment: Thanks @ Run for providing the proper syntax.

Answer (score 3):

You'd use jQuery [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

However, jQuery is not able to interpolate colors by default, so you'll need to use the [color animation plugin](http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/) or (as Niklas stated) [jQuery UI Effects](http://jqueryui.com/demos/animate/).

Comment: @Niklas indeed, added that to the answer.

Comment: Thank you perfect. I attributed the answer to @Run, however, because they provided the syntax also. Thank you.