# Change background of a div quickly with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I'm tryin to animate the background change with jQuery on a div.

This is what I have actually but it doesn't work.

Do you know why ?

Thanks.

```js
$("#banner-message").click(function(){
    for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++ ) {
        $(this)
        .animate({ backgroundColor: "#343a40", color: "#ffffff"}, 20)
        .animate({ backgroundColor: "transparent", color: "#343a40"}, 20);
    }
});
```

```css
#banner-message {
  background: red;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message"></div>
```

Comment: jQuery can't interpolate the hex values , you would need a plugin for that.See https://stackoverflow.com/a/8149877/1175966    Can do the color changes with css alone

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the [jQuery Color](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color) plugin.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-color/2.1.2/jquery.color.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message"></div>
```